# How to use bootstrap in Liferay?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, liferay

I'm trying to use Bootstrap in my JSP's for my Liferay portlet. I'm aware that liferay also uses bootstrap. So how can I import bootstrap without any conflicts in my portlet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using LR 6.2, then bootstrap will be their in your portal on every page. You just need to invoke the appropriate module of the bootstrap. Rest the js and css files required will be provided by the theme.

Comment: I would like to add that Liferay 6.2 is using the quite old bootstrap version [2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2). This is important to notice, as newer versions have changed substantially.

Answer (score 3):

From liferay 6.2 bootstrap CSS are included natively. So you can just use it.
The scripts of bootstrap instead are not included and if you want it you have to import manually.