# Get wrong if import bootstrap css to liferay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, liferay

In my liferay poject I import js and css

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>Register</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/style.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/bootstrap.min.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/jquery.min.js</footer-portlet-javascript>        
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/bootstrap.min.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
```

But in my http://localhost:8080/ mange tools are hide (add, preview, edit...). When I remove bootstrap.css, it showed.
Can you tell me reason. How to use bootstrap with liferay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use bootstrap in Liferay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117699/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-liferay)

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap CSS is already included within Liferay, if you are using Liferay 6.2 the version of bootstrap is 2.3.2: so you can just use his classes like `spanX`, `container` ecc...

But the JS of bootstrap are **not** included, they are replicated (more or less) with [Alloy](http://alloyui.com/): the JS framework of Liferay.